# Graaljs script engine evaluate on java script string condition

Tags: javascript, java-11, graaljs

I am using jdk11, graal.js script engine .

We get two json string messages, one has rules/condition(jsRules) and the other one has message.  If the value in message satisfies the condition in jsRules it should evaluate to 1 else 0 .

So for example in the below code as String "message" has `code: CU_USER` hence the jsRules condition

```
header.code == 'CU_USER'
```

should have been satisfied and hence the eval below should have printed 1 , but instead it gives 0.  Kindly explain what is causing this behavior and how can I get the desired behavior ? .

```
public static void process()
{
    int eval =-2 ;
    String jsRules = "{(header.code == 'CU_USER' || header.subcode == 'SD_CODE')?1:0}";
    String message = "{code:'CU_USER'}";
    
    ScriptEngine graalEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("Graal.js");
    //graalEngine.put("header",message);
    try {
        graalEngine.eval("var header = unescape(" + message + ")");
        eval = (int)graalEngine.eval(jsRules);
        System.out.println("Eval value::  "+eval);
    } catch (ScriptException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `unescape({code:'CU_USER'})` while unescape expects a String. Thus, the object you provide as argument is converted to a String (to `[object Object]` actually) and thus the `header` variable on the JavaScript side holds a String, not an Object as you expect.

The solution would be to simply remove the `unescape`, i.e. use `graalEngine.eval("var header = " + message);` instead.

---

An alternative solution would be to pass in a Java object. You seem to have tried that with the commented out `graalEngine.put("header",message);` line. Note that I suppose don't want to pass in a Java string; what you typically want to pass in was a Java object that has a `code` field. Note that for this to work you need to enable the `hostAccess` permission to the engine (for more details, check https://github.com/graalvm/graaljs/blob/master/docs/user/ScriptEngine.md).

solution draft:

```
public static class MyMessageObj {
  public String code = "CU_USER";
}

ScriptEngine graalEngine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
Bindings bindings = graalEngine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowHostAccess", true);
graalEngine.put("header", new MyMessageObj());
eval = (int) graalEngine.eval(jsRules);
```